# Treat my own get/set C++ member functions as a member variable in SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig

At its lowest level, SWIG handles [C++ class member variables](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_member_data) by generating a pair of accessor functions, e.g. from:

```
class List {
public:
    int length;
    ...
};
```

SWIG creates:

```
int List_length_get(List *obj) { return obj->length; }
int List_length_set(List *obj, int value) {
    obj->length = value;
    return value;
}
```

Can I provide my own accessors, and tell SWIG to use them to create a "virtual" member variable in, say, Python? E.g. from this:

```
class List {
public:
    int setLength(int aLength) { _length = aLength; return _length; }
    int getLength() { return _length; }
    ...
private:
    int _length;
    ...
};
```

tell SWIG to let me do this:

```
>>> l = List();
>>> print(l.length)
```

in Python?

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, you should be able to use `%attributeref` to accomplish this. Something like `%attributeref (List, int, Length);`, but you'd have to provide a function like `int& Length()` rather than an individual getter/setter. However, I could certainly see a hack to do what you need.

Comment: Looking more into it `%attribute(List, int, length, getLength, setLength);` may do what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I am not violating any copyright stuff here.

From http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/attribute-directive-and-C-templates-td11288.html

> I recently discovered how to use `attribute.i` and the `%attribute` 
>   directive to create attributes with customized behavior, as in the 
>   following (superfluous) example:
>
> ```
> %attribute(Point, int, x, getX, setX); 
> %attribute(Point, int, y, getY, setY); 
> class Point { 
> public: 
>     int getX() { return _x }; 
>     void setX(int x) { _x = x }; 
>     int getY() { return _y }; 
>     void setY(int y) { _y = y }; 
> private: 
>    int _x; 
>    int _y; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for.